# Angular 11 - Display user email after login

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am using Angular 11 and .NET Core with web API JWT token authentication to create user Login. I successfully created the user login and it successfully redirects to the dashboard, but I don't know how to display the logged in user email in my toolbar in dashboard.
I have to done it that after successful login.

`loginservice.ts`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/login.service';
    
@Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    
    credentials={
        useUserID:'',
        useUserPassword:''
    }
    constructor(private loginService:LoginService) { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {}
    
    onSubmit(){
      if((this.credentials.useUserID!='' && this.credentials.useUserPassword!='')&& (this.credentials.useUserID!=null && this.credentials.useUserPassword!=null ))
        {
          console.log("We have to submitt the form");
    
          //token generate
          this.loginService.generateToken(this.credentials).subscribe(
            (response:any)=>{
              //success (parameter) response:Object
              console.log(response.token);
              this.loginService.loginUser(response.token)
              window.location.href="/dashboard"
            },
            //error
            error=>{
            console.log(error);
            }
          )
          
    
        }else
        console.log("Field are empty");  
      }
    
}
```

`logincomponent.ts`:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
@Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
    
      url="http://"
    
      constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    
      //calling the server to generate token
     generateToken(credentials:any){
        return this.http.post(`${this.url}/token`,credentials,{responseType:"text"})
      }
    
      //for login user
      loginUser(token)
      {
        localStorage.setItem("token",token)
        return true;
    
      }
    
      //to check that user login or not
    
      isLoggedIn()
      {
        let token=localStorage.getItem("token");
        if(token==undefined || token=== '' || token==null)
        {
          return false;
    
        }
        else {
          return true;
        }
      }
      //To logout the user
      logout ()
      {
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        return true;
      }
    
      //for gettinh the token
      getToken()
      {
        return localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First install the package `jwt-decode` via `npm i jwt-decode`

Import it to your component like this `import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';`

Then load the JWT Token from local storage and decode it:

```
token = localStorage.getItem("token");
email = jwt_decode(this.token)['email'];
```

html

```
<p>{{email}}</p>
```

Inspect your JWT Token with [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) to make sure, that the email is included.